# Scikit Learn Not fit error when calling LinearRegression

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, spyder

I am calling LinearRegression using this code in Spyder:

```
 X = Full[predictors]
Y = Full['logerror']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split( X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train_val = X_train.values
Y_train_val = Y_train.values
X_test_val = X_test.values


model = LinearRegression()

LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)

pred = model.predict(X_test_val)
```

it shows this error: NotFittedError: This LinearRegression instance is not fitted yet.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not do any fitting.

```
model = LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
model.fit(X_train_val, Y_train_val)
```

would be some code doing that compatible to yours.

**Edit:** there is more broken stuff in your code i think (or you are hiding some pandas-based usage)! Read the docs more carefully.

Have a look at [the tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html), the basic example being:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit ([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: I only cut short the code so it can concentrate to the part with error

Comment: Thank you very much! it helps to fix the problem ! :)

Comment: @user1314404 That's good in general, but the ```.values``` part looks strange without any pandas-indication (yeah, the first two lines made me think it's pandas).

Comment: you are right indeed ! the first few lines: import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split